# In which case should I use dependency injection with Hilt in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have read the [article](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) about DI.

I try to use dependency injection with Hilt to instance every class in my Android Compose project, but it make me confused.

1: You know some classes such as `ComponentActivity`, `Service` can't be instanced by Hilt.

2: Althogh  some system classes can be instanced by Hilt just like Code A, it's hard to release.

3: In the sample [project](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/addedittask/AddEditTaskViewModel.kt) ,
the instance of `AddEditTaskUiState` is created manually, you can see Code B.

4: In the sample [project](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Crane/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/home/MainViewModel.kt) ,
the instance of `CalendarState` is created manually, you can see Code C.

In which case should I use dependency injection with Hilt in an Android Studio project ?

**Code A**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ProvideModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMediaPlayer(): MediaPlayer {
        return MediaPlayer()
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
data class AddEditTaskUiState(
    val title: String = "",
    ...
)

@HiltViewModel
class AddEditTaskViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val taskRepository: TaskRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
   ...
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(AddEditTaskUiState())
    ...
}
```

**Code C**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    @DefaultDispatcher private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {    
    val calendarState = CalendarState()
    ...
}


class CalendarState {
    val calendarUiState = mutableStateOf(CalendarUiState())
    val listMonths: List<Month>
    private val calendarStartDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now()
          .withMonth(1).withDayOfMonth(1)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the purpose of dependency injection is to minimize tight coupling of the classes. Why?

1. To ease unit testing
2. Improve code reusability by apply fifth principle (i.e. Dependency inversion principle) of SOLID

Now there are two main questions:

1. Which class instance can we create that will be injected? Any instance can be created. How to create an instance? (See Modules, Scopes etc. in the hilt documentation). They can be injected either via a field injection or a constructor injection.
2. After creation , In which classes can they be injected? So for Hilt, In Android classes as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes) and the classes which are injected in other classes (e.g. if your Repository Class is an injected class in a viewModel then Repository can also use injected dependencies).

Now regarding the specific classes. You wont inject an Activity or a Service in another class. Not that you can't, but you won't/shouldn't, there is no point in injecting them. Like, Why would you want an Activity/Service instance in an another class. More practically, rather you should inject a viewModel in an activity, or may be a Repository in a ViewModel as they will have to use the instance of the class. Or as You mentioned, an instance of a MediaPlayer class (depending upon the use case).

So now how does it address our 2 purposes.

1. How is the code testable now? Now as a classes are loosely coupled, a class will depend on an instance created by the hilt library, so for example for unit testing you can provide a mock instance to the SUT class!
2. How did we achieve inversion of control? Rather than classes controlling the instances, the instances are controlling the class behaviour. So By switching the injected instances we can play with the classes (like in testing we injected mocked instances) thus improving code reusabiltiy. Secondly, By creating interfaces, we can bind them with their implementation classes in Module and then inject the interface in our required class. For example A repository is needed in a ViewModel, so by making a RepostoryImpl class that implements an interface, binding the interface to the implementation class in the Module and injecting the interface (**Not the implementation class**) in the viewmodel class, our Viewmodel (High level module) is not depending on a Repository (low level module) rather both are depending on an abstraction i.e. interface (and hence improving code reusability as interfaces can have multiple implementations and viewmodel depending upon interfaces can use any implementation)

**Edit**: Some mistakes corrected in the original answer.